# Keyboard shortcuts window resize

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu on a laptop with 4k screen, since what I had to zoom up the fonts a bit. But the keyboard shortcuts is not resizeable in any way, so it's impossible even to find out what shortcut is what. May I make this window resizeable?

[Keyboard shortcuts window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Gz0.png)